# Ruby merge a nested array based on inner array's first element

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a nested Ruby array:

```
array = [["id1", "Mike", "a", "aa"],
         ["id1", "Mike", "a", "bb"],
         ["id1", "Mike", "a", "cc"],
         ["id1", "Mike", "b", "aa"],
         ["id1", "Mike", "b", "bb"],
         ["id1", "Mike", "b", "cc"],
         ["id2", "Joe", "a", "aa"],
         ["id2", "Joe", "a", "bb"],
         ["id2", "Joe", "a", "cc"],
         ["id2", "Joe", "b", "aa"],
         ["id2", "Joe", "b", "bb"],
         ["id2", "Joe", "b", "cc"],
         ["id2", "Joe", "c", "aa"],
         ["id2", "Joe", "c", "bb"],
         ["id2", "Joe", "c", "cc"]]
```

I want to merge it based on the first element, with grouping as such:

```
result = [["id1", "Mike", ["a", "b"], ["aa", "bb", "cc"]],
          ["id2", "Joe", ["a", "b", "c"], ["aa", "bb", "cc"]]]
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: The result you have given is wrong, I think the second one is id2, yes?

Comment: You're right, I fixed the typo. Thanks for your answer! It's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code

```
result = array.group_by { |a| [a[0], a[1]] }.map do |k, v|
  v.map { |id, name, v1, v2| [v1, v2] }.transpose.map(&:uniq).prepend(*k)
end

p result
```

Output

```
[["id1", "Mike", ["a", "b"], ["aa", "bb", "cc"]], ["id2", "Joe", ["a", "b", "c"], ["aa", "bb", "cc"]]]
```